# How to remove spaces from a string in Lua?

Tags: lua, replace

I want to remove all spaces from a string in Lua. This is what I have tried:

```
string.gsub(str, "", "")
string.gsub(str, "% ", "")
string.gsub(str, "%s*", "")
```

This does not seem to work. How can I remove all of the spaces?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It works, you just have to assign the actual result/return value. Use one of the following variations:

```
str = str:gsub("%s+", "")
str = string.gsub(str, "%s+", "")
```

I use `%s+` as there's no point in replacing an empty match (i.e. there's no space). This just doesn't make any sense, so I look for at least one space character (using the `+` quantifier).

Comment: You really don't need to use +, it won't match non-space if you just use %s. Using %s seems more common - though I guess the end result is the same.

Comment: The end result will be the same, but with `+` you'll replace spaces following each other in one go which might be more performant (not really sure if it really matters in Lua).

Comment: Neither am i. Just worth a mention.

Answer (score 11):

You use the following function :

```
function all_trim(s)
  return s:match"^%s*(.*)":match"(.-)%s*$"
end
```

Or shorter :

```
function all_trim(s)
   return s:match( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" )
end
```

usage:

```
str=" aa " 
print(all_trim(str) .. "e")
```

Output is:

```
aae
```

Comment: Or even shorter and in one go: `s:match( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" )`.

Comment: I used your suggesstion but i get the `stdin:1: attempt to concatenate a nil value`

Comment: The code I gave works and never produces `nil` as result for any input string. Did you return the result? Or did you forget the quotes around `"e"`?

Comment: Ok, here the complete code for copy/pasting: `function all_trim(s) return s:match( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" ) end; str = " aa "; print( all_trim( str ) .. "e" )`. And this works fine here.

Comment: You forgot the `return`.

Comment: Nice trim function. But the OP was asking to remove ALL spaces; not just leading and trailing ones :-)

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way is to use trim.so compiled from trim.c:

```
/* trim.c - based on http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-12/msg00951.html
            from Sean Conner */
#include <stddef.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int trim(lua_State *L)
{
 const char *front;
 const char *end;
 size_t      size;

 front = luaL_checklstring(L,1,&size);
 end   = &front[size - 1];

 for ( ; size && isspace(*front) ; size-- , front++)
   ;
 for ( ; size && isspace(*end) ; size-- , end--)
   ;

 lua_pushlstring(L,front,(size_t)(end - front) + 1);
 return 1;
}

int luaopen_trim(lua_State *L)
{
 lua_register(L,"trim",trim);
 return 0;
}
```

compile something like:

```
gcc -shared -fpic -O -I/usr/local/include/luajit-2.1 trim.c -o trim.so
```

More detailed (with comparison to the other methods): http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringTrim

**Usage:**

```
local trim15 = require("trim")--at begin of the file
local tr = trim("   a z z z z z    ")--anywhere at code
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit . Unless you have a whole library it makes very little sense to do this, I think

Comment: @Daniel it was made 7 years ago. Maybe nowadays there is a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

For LuaJIT all methods from Lua wiki (except for, possibly, native C/C++) were awfully slow in my tests. This implementation showed the best performance:

```
function trim (str)
  if str == '' then
    return str
  else  
    local startPos = 1
    local endPos   = #str

    while (startPos < endPos and str:byte(startPos) <= 32) do
      startPos = startPos + 1
    end

    if startPos >= endPos then
      return ''
    else
      while (endPos > 0 and str:byte(endPos) <= 32) do
        endPos = endPos - 1
      end

      return str:sub(startPos, endPos)
    end
  end
end -- .function trim
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking to remove all spaces in a bunch of strings, and remove spaces in the middle of the string, this this works for me:

```
function noSpace(str)

  local normalisedString = string.gsub(str, "%s+", "")

  return normalisedString

end

test = "te st"

print(noSpace(test))
```

Might be that there is an easier way though, I'm no expert!