# Lua trailing space removal

Tags: string, lua

I'm using Lua in the NodeMCU environment. I saw the approach for whitespace trimming [presented in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10460126/how-to-remove-spaces-from-a-string-in-lua).

The answer suggests this form:

```
str = string.gsub(str, "%s+", "")
```

I found it does not have any effect. Here is output from interactive commands (using LuaLoader).

```
> print("|",part1,"|")
|   172.16.0.19 |
> part1a = string.gsub(part1, "%s+", "")

> print("|",part1a,"|")
|   172.16.0.19 |
>
```

If I examine the strings in hex, I see that there are some tabs. Apparently %s (the whitespace pattern) does not consider tab a whitespace. Is there a setting to cause %s to match tab (0x09)?

Comment: I found %c as the pattern for control characters, so I tried part1a = string.gsub(part1a, "%c+", "").    That still has no effect on the string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `print` function prints its arguments with tabs between them (after converting them to strings with `tostring`). To check this properly, use `io.write` (which does not add tabs between its arguments and only converts numbers to strings):

```
str = '   172.16.0.19 '
stripped = string.gsub(str, '%s+', '')
io.write('|', str, '|\n')
io.write('|', stripped, '|\n')
```

Note that this will remove all spaces and newlines, even if they are inside the string. To remove those on either end:

```
str = string.gsub(str, '^%s*(.-)%s*$', '%1')
```

or at the ends of lines and the end of the string:

```
str = string.gsub(str, '[ \t]+%f[\r\n%z]', '')
```

Comment: Thank you - I'm obviously new to Lua. I had no idea Print would modify strings like that.  From now on, I'll use io.write for debugging.

Comment: Well, don't give up on `print` altogether. I find `print` is often useful for debugging. It's often helpful to have it convert all arguments to a string and print them with tabs between them and a newline at the end. It's just not the best choice if you need to see whitespace in a string.

Comment: Hey @cyclaminist, the second code block really helped me. How can I remove the one space before and after linebreaks from the string? I tried to simply `str:gsub('\n', '')` but it didn't work. I assume that I need to use some of these "%s", "[\n]" signs, but I have no experience with them.

Comment: `str:gsub('\n', '')` removes all line breaks in `str`; it doesn't do anything to spaces. To remove all optional single spaces before and after line breaks, if there are any, use `str:gsub(' ?\n ?', '\n')`. I'm not sure what the purpose is but hopefully that is what you want. If it doesn't work, you might want to post a separate question with more information.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `print(something,somethingElse)`, do `print(something..somethingElse)`. Concatenate the separate components - don’t just print a comma-separated list of the strings.